# Gitlab userPrincipalName without Domain

Tags: ldap, git

I've to use the userPrincipalName instead of the default sAMAccountName in all applications which are integrated to AD because we've login-names > 20 characters which isn't supported by sAMAccountName. 
So i changed

```
gitlab_rails['ldap_uid'] = 'sAMAccountName'
```

to

```
gitlab_rails['ldap_uid'] = 'userPrincipalName'
```

in my /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb config.
That's working, but now I need to enter the login-name AND the domain. 
Example: 
A User login is called "Peter". With the sAMAccountName I was able to login by enter "Peter" as Username in Gitlab. But because of the userPrincipalName contains the domain, I now have to enter "Peter@mydomain.com".

I'm looking to give my users the comfort to enter only the Loginname, without @domain. 
Something like this so that the User enter "Peter" and git send "Peter@mydomain.com" to the AD:

```
 gitlab_rails['ldap_uid'] = '${gitlabUsername}@mydomain.com'
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your gitlab.rb:

```
  ##
  ## If allow_username_or_email_login is enabled, GitLab will ignore everything
  ## after the first '@' in the LDAP username submitted by the user on login.
  ##
  ## Example:
  ## - the user enters 'jane.doe@example.com' and 'p@ssw0rd' as LDAP credentials;
  ## - GitLab queries the LDAP server with 'jane.doe' and 'p@ssw0rd'.
  ##
  ## If you are using "uid: 'userPrincipalName'" on ActiveDirectory you need to
  ## disable this setting, because the userPrincipalName contains an '@'.
  ##
  allow_username_or_email_login: false
```